# Date-based permalinks for Custom Post Type, and custom taxonomy permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

In my theme (a child of Twenty Sixteen) I've created a new Custom Post Type, `pg_review`. I've associated two custom taxonomies with it, `pg_genres` (hierarchical categories), and `pg_authors` (like tags).

Everything is working fine except permalinks... Despite trying to understand and [adapt](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/custom-post-type-permalinks-part-2) [various](https://web.archive.org/web/20110414132146/http://madpress.org/display-date-in-custom-post-type-permalinks/564/) [examples](https://angrycreative.se/wordpress-development-custom-post-types-and-permalinks/) I'm going round in circles.

I would like these permalinks to work:

```
/reading/2017/02/19/post-name/  # A single Review.
/reading/2017/02/19/            # Reviews from one day.
/reading/2017/02/               # Reviews from one month.
/reading/2017/                  # Reviews from one year
/reading/                       # The most recent Reviews (this is working).
/reading/genre/genre-name/      # Reviews in a `pg_genre`.
/reading/author/author-name/    # Reviews in a `pg_author'.
```

This is pretty much how conventional Posts work if given a custom permalink structure like `/archive/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`. But how do I make this work for a Custom Post Type?

(I've tried the [Custom Post Type Permalinks plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) which promises to do this, but the links for taxonomies 404 (a problem others in support seem to have too).)

Comment: Here's an article that provides a copypasta class where you can just replace their values with your own to get your custom post working. It also explains the various parts of the code in pretty detailed manner: https://blog.terresquall.com/2021/03/making-date-based-permalinks-for-custom-posts-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We'll start with the taxonomies, as those are fairly simple. If you register those with simply `reading/genre` and `reading/author` as the `slug` argument, those should work without issue.

The post type is a bit more tricky. For that, we register with the `rewrite` argument set to just `true`. Then we add a new permastruct for that post type with:

```
add_permastruct(
    'pg_review',
    "/reading/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%pg_review%/",
    array( 'with_front' => false )
);
```

We'll now have the rules for single post views, but the year/month/day views will all have the wrong post type set, so we'll add some new rules to reset those with:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^reading/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=pg_review&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]',
    'top'
);
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^reading/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=pg_review&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^reading/([0-9]{4})/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=pg_review&year=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

The last step is to filter `post_type_link` to insert the correct year/month/day in the permalinks:

```
function wpd_pg_review_permalinks( $url, $post ) {
    if ( 'pg_review' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        $url = str_replace( "%year%", get_the_date('Y'), $url );
        $url = str_replace( "%monthnum%", get_the_date('m'), $url );
        $url = str_replace( "%day%", get_the_date('d'), $url );
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpd_pg_review_permalinks', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this Milo, so helpful! Nearly there... On the post type I had to keep `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'reading', 'with_front' => false,)` in order for the `/reading/` page to keep working. I had to add another `add_rewrite_rule()` to match the full `/reading/yyyy/mm/dd/name/` path for a single review. And when filtering `post_type_link` add `$url = str_replace( "%reading%", $post->post_name, $url );`.

Comment: The only thing that's not quite right is the taxonomies' URLs are like `/blog/reading/genre/[name]/` and `/blog/reading/author/[name]/` I can't work out how to get rid of the `/blog` from the start - that's used for all the standard WP Posts. I've tried the taxonomies' `rewrite`s having both `'with_front'=>'false'` and without, but no difference.

Comment: `'false'` is a string and evaluates to true, it should be `'with_front' => false` without quotes.

Comment: Doh, of course, well spotted Milo! The taxonomies' links are now correct! However, I've spotted that the year/month/day archives, like `/reading/2017/`, only show Posts, not my custom `pg_review` post types.

Comment: `/reading/2017/` shows standard Posts from that year, but `/reading/2017/?post_type=pg_review` does show Reviews.

Comment: hmm, the order may matter here. Are you calling `add_rewrite_rule` before or after you register the post type? Install [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins-wp/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) and look for it under the Tools menu, it'll tell you what rewrite rules are matching different requests and may shed some light on why it's not matching.

Comment: The rules are in the same function that registers the post type, but after `register_post_type()` in that function. Which plugin?

Comment: Ah! I was missing the `^` at the start of the paths in `add_rewrite_rule()`! Now everything is working :) Thank you so much Milo.